# CPU Usage during glFinish()

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

**Context** : I am measuring the cpu usage during the graphical rendering of a Qt test Application. The rendering is done via the Qt Quick module, which makes use of a dedicated scene graph based on OpenGL.

**Environment** : I run the tests on a mobile panel running Windows CE and I track the CPU activity with the Celog Event Tracker.

**Problem** : When QQuickWindow emits the signals afterRendering() and frameSwapped(), I call the glFinish() function.
Since glFinish() job is to wait for all previous opengl commands to complete, I understand that the CPU should just be waiting for the GPU to complete the tasks. And I therefore expected to have a very low CPU usage during that call.
However, this is not what I observe with the celog tracker. I can observe that, during the glFinish() time frame, some threads belonging to the test app are still using the CPU. And in the end the CPU usage is in the same range as the rest of the rendering loop.

So I was wondering, is there an explanation to the CPU being used while glFinish() is running ?

Comment: I can't speak for Windows CE, but I know that drivers running on plain old Windows using a GPU from the likes of AMD or nVidia are multithreaded. They will spawn multiple _usermode_ threads in your process to handle all sorts of things for OpenGL like data conversion, command scheduling, etc. You will find this out sooner or later developing on Windows when a thread you don't have anything to do with causes a crash in some AMD or nVidia DLL :P Do you have any way of knowing which DLL created those threads?

Comment: Yes, I have very detailed information on the Celog file and I can tell that the threads in question were created within the test application's process. 
To be more specific, the test app creates 3 threads, with only one of them really active. This thread uses the cpu at every step of the rendering loop, including this glFinish function.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL employs an asynchronous execution model. OpenGL commands are queued up in a render command pipeline and the pipeline may not be executed at all and the queued up commands lay dormant until the pipeline execution is forced by *flushing* the pipeline with `glFlush` or making a synchronizing OpenGL call, that causes an implicit flush and wait like `glFinish` (or `…SwapBuffers`).

Hence it's not really surprising if things get busy on the CPU and the GPU after a call to `glFlush`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that things get busy on the GPU since it has to deal with all the queued up OpenGL commands. But shouldn't the CPU be in idle state while waiting for the GPU ?
I mean, I thought the OpenGL commands where run mainly on the GPU, am I wrong ?